# Split Keyed file, in order to achieve multithreading

Tags: rpgle

I did multi threading on RRN basis earlier.
This time my file is Keyed (6 keys) and defined as Key seq in RPGLE program...
Because of millions of record the requirement is to split file in 10 thread for processing....
Not sure how to achieve splitting on keyed file, not on RRN.
please advise. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to process it by key?

Assuming you're going to process the whole thing anyway, RRN is just as valid for a keyed file as it is for a non-keyed one.

Access file by key

```
FDIVPODIT  UF A E           K DISK
```

Access the same file by RRN

```
FDIVPODIT  UF A E             DISK
```

All you need to do is leave off the K

If you really need keyed access, you'd have to examine the distribution of the keys and subkeys and come up with some some algorithm for splitting them.

What I mean is that if for instance, the first key is a number from 1 to 10 and each has approximately the same number of records...then splitting into 10 threads is obvious.

Note: even though the file has 6 keys, you don't have to use them all, both of these are equally valid for the same f-spec declared file.

```
setll (ky1:ky2:k3:k4:k5) myfile;
setll (k1) myfile;
```

The technique is call "partial keys".

Another thought, lets say that K3 is a number from 1 to 10, again with a equal group of records.  You could simply create a logical or SQL index with K3 as the first (and possibly) only key.

Without more info on the sub-key distribution, I can't suggest anything more.

Lastly note that SQL offers count & distinct functionality that may help you analyse the key distribution.

```
select count(distinct ky1) from myfile
select ky1, count(*) from myfile
```

`DSPFD` may also be of use as part of the information shown includes:

```
Number of unique partial key values . . :                           
  Key field 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . :                          1
  Key fields 1 - 2  . . . . . . . . . . :                      48876
  Key fields 1 - 3  . . . . . . . . . . :                  111861652
```

Comment: It's old program and file defined as a keyed and there is SETLL and READE... then then doW..readE.....
because this file has Run ID so they want to read only latest runID data...

Comment: so you only want to process the latest `RunID`? Have you tried doing this with a single thread and ended up with poor performance? How many records do you really need to read? Is it millions in a single `RunId`? Do you have a logical keyed by `RunID`?

Comment: So assuming RUNID is the first key, what's the distribution of the values in second key?  `select count(distinct key2) from mytable where runId = 'xx'`  Are you updating any sort of processed flag in the records?